# Using a pi to activate a button on another device

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4

**Background about the problem**

I run two different computers for work, and I'm shifting between them very often. I currently use 2 aux switches, 2 USB switches, and 2 HDMI switches to make the process of switching between computers more effortless. But having all that stuff on my desk makes the cable sphagetti situation pretty infuriating.

**What I'm trying to do to solve it**

I want to break all these components open and try to make it so the raspberry pi can replace the buttons on these switches, and I can develop a user interface in python to make the process happen with the press of a button on my touchscreen, instead of having cable spaghetti and pressing a bunch of different buttons.

**My question**

What would I need to get/do to make the raspberry pi actually actuate the buttons on the other device? Programming is something I don't really have a problem with. I can solder, and I can desolder, but I'm unfamiliar with how to actually hook up a pi to other electronics in general. What do I hook into where? What would I need to do to get the pi to turn the switch on and off?

Do you have any resources you can point me to that can teach me to do something like this?

Comment: Perhaps this is a better question for [the raspberry pi stack exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: So I guess you're saying you have a monitor, keyboard, mouse, and speakers that you switch between two computers?  Have you looked into remote desktop or VNC or TeamViewer solutions  (or are the two computers not on a network?).  To replace switches you probably will need a dry contact relay board to go with the GPIO on the Pi.  It could get complicated if the switches are multipole switches inside your switch boxes, which they could well be.   You may be better off investing in a KVM switch that handles all these (although it looks like aux-including ones are $$$)